# Disabling Incremental Linking in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, dll, linker

I'm trying to run a large solution (200 projects) under Rational Purify, which balks on DLLs linked using `/INCREMENTAL:YES`. I've already removed all explicit properties that enable the incremental linker in Debug mode from the project files; however the default setting of `YES` still applies.

Where can I disable this in VS2008, either for an entire solution, or globally?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately(or not) it needs to be explicitly disabled, as it defaults to 'YES', see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4khtbfyf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> By default, the linker runs in incremental mode